# Dealing with Async calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got into a small trouble here. In my document.ready function I've defined an object and that object is being populated by three different ajax calls(inside document.ready). Now I want to do a

```
 console.log(myObject);
```

only when the 3 async calls have been executed completely. Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Using I would suggest you to create a function like this:

```
function onAllInformationIsReady() {
        console.log(myObject);
    }

function isAllInformationReady() {
    // verify here if you have all the information
}
```

and you do something like this on your ajax calls (I'm not assuming you are using jQuery here, replace with your ajax call method)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "...n",
    success: function(msg){

     if(isAllInformationReady())
        onAllInformationIsReady();

    }
});
```

By the way, if you are using jQuery you can make synchronous ajax calls like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "...n",
        async: false,
        success: function(msg){

        }
    });
```

Comment: yes, I'm using jQuery, but the issue is that I'm making 3 simultaneous calls. In who's success part should I call my method?

Comment: don't - use the `$.when` method from my answer which is now the "right" way to handle collation of multiple asynchronous tasks in jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Try jQuery 1.5's new "[deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)" objects:

```
var j1 = $.ajax(...);
var j2 = $.ajax(...);
var j3 = $.ajax(...);

j1.success(function(data) {
    // do something with data
});

j2.success(function(data) {
    // do something with data
});

j3.success(function(data) {
    // do something with data
});

$.when(j1, j2, j3).done(function() {
    console.log(myObject);
});
```

The three `.success()` functions will be called asynchronously and will populate `myObject`, and then the `done` function will only be invoked by `$.when()` once all three AJAX requests have been completed.